# Matching two files, line by line?

Tags: shell

I have two files consisting of numbers. Now, I want to match the line of first file to all the line of second file and increasing the counter if the match is found. How to write the bash script for this ?

```
file1:
1
2
3
4
5
6
file2:
2
3
6
10
12
13
23
counter = 3
```

Comment: Can you give input and desired output?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of you data and desired output?

Comment: grep -c ^<backtick> head -n1 < file1<backtick>$ < file2

Comment: @user80551 Please see [this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15101/discussion-between-caleb-and-user80551) for my feedback on your comment. (I'm removing my other comments as they are duplicated in chat)

Comment: What about desired **output**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` have sets of numbers like this:

`file1.txt`:

```
1
2
4
6
7
```

`file2.txt`:

```
2
6
7
8
9
```

You could try a couple approaches depending on what you want to do with the data or what else you want to collect along the way.

- Grep can search through a file for a pattern string. The patterns can be supplied using another file using the `-f` flag. The `-x` flag also makes sure you only find whole line matches so that a pattern of '2' does not match '24'. Finally the `-c` flag counts the number of matches. Putting it all together you would have:

  ```
  grep -x -c -f file1.txt file2.txt
  ```
- If you wanted to do other things with the numbers along the way other that get a total count, you could take a more manual approach:

  ```
  counter=0
  while read number; do
      grep -q -x "$number" file2.txt && let counter=$counter+1
  done < file1.txt
  echo $counter
  ```

  This is much less efficient as you are reading file2.txt again for every line in file1.txt, but if you also wanted to do other things with the number or manipulate the file along the way it would be easier to patch onto a loop like that. Not the use of the `-q` flag so grep is silent and only returns an exit code. Using that code we can tell if a match was found or not and only increment the counter if it was.

Any way you work this make sure you take into account the possibility that some lines will be partial matches for numbers that are sub-strings of other numbers. Also you need to think about what you want to happen if there is more than one match per line. Does each duplicate increment the counter or does that only happen once. Note the two options above handle this differently! For some data sets they will give different results. If you wanted them to give the same results both techniques could be adapted. For example the first one could check a version of the file that has all the duplicates removed so nothing will match more than once:

```
 grep -x -c -f <(sort -u file1.txt) <(sort -u file2.txt)
```